# Raspberry Pi 2 With Chromecast 2

Tags: osmc, chromecast

I'm running OSMC on my Raspberry Pi 2 with a Chromecast 2 connected to my TV.

I'd like to create an integrated media centre experience so it should be easy to switch to the Chromecast from OSMC but that everything is controlled through OSMC with it being the central interface.

Is this possible?

Comment: I just bought a Raspberry Pi 2. Did you find any answer to your question? I would like to use my Raspberry Pi as a mediacenter with osmc, but not plugged on the TV. I've got a chromecast on the TV and I would like to use my phone to controle the media center and send media to the chromecast. Do yoy think it's possible? Jean

Comment: @jeasto Please just ask the question as a seperate question, not in a comment on someone else's question.

Comment: @motionpotion What is it exactly that you want to do? Controle your chromecast with osmc, or replace the chromecast with kodi? It's not really clear to me

Comment: @Havnar i want to control Chromecast through the osmc as another source. For example, the TV itself can be controlled as another device or similarly the satellite box is just another device.